# How to execute asynchronous PHP echoes (JavaScript code) as they occur?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, echo

I have a page with a custom Google Map that has about 100-150 markers. The marker data is obtained by parsing, via external PHP, an XML file which is a list of events/projects, but within each event is the appropriate data to create a marker.

Currently everything is working, but it takes awhile for the map to load because parsing the XML file is taking some time. To speed things up, I essentially want to load the page dynamically by drawing a blank map upon page load, then run the external PHP file to parse the XML asynchronously using AJAX and add the markers to the map as they are echoed out from the asynch. PHP loop.

What I don't know how to do is execute these echoes as they come.

The page that has the map (explore.php) runs the JavaScript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">;
        function init() {
            // Draw the map (blank)
            var map_focus = new google.maps.LatLng(35,-37);
            var myOptions = { zoom: 2,center: map_focus,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };  
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            // Run PHP to parse XML, asynchronously
            xmlhttp.open("GET","project_locations.php",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            // This is where I want the JS/AJAX to execute echoes as they come from the above call to project_locations.php
            eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
        // Add marker to map. Markers would appear as fast as the XML is parsed
        function addMarker(object, name, id) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(object,"click", function() {
                window.location = "showproject.php?id=" + id;
            });
        }
    </script>
```

And this is project_locations.php:

```
include('spparser.php'); // Parse XML
$i = 0;
foreach(SPParser::search($_REQUEST) as $index=>$sp) {
    if ($sp["latitude"] != '' && $sp["longitude"] != '') {
        echo "var marker" . $i . "= new google.maps.Marker({\n";
            echo "position: new google.maps.LatLng(" . $sp["latitude"] . ", " . $sp["longitude"] . "),\n";
            echo "map: map,\n";
            echo "icon: 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/" . $sp["color"] . "-dot.png',\n";
            echo "title: \"" . $sp["name"] . "\"\n";
        echo "});\n\n";
        echo "addMarker(marker" . $i . ", \"" . $sp["name"] . "\", " . $sp["id"] . ");\n";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

The above code draws a blank map and that's it. However, if I run it synchronously by using:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","project_locations.php",false);
```

There is a long delay, then the map and all the markers are drawn, meaning the eval() statement that comes after send() executes all of the echoes at the end. How do I execute them in real-time as they are echoed by project_locations.php?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Is the code snippet above a file that is called using AJAX?

Comment: I just added another snippet, but yes, the first code snipped would be called via AJAX (sans those 3 lines I commented about). Perhaps I should recode what I know how to do first, then see if anyone here can help me find the missing piece.

Comment: @Sooie So what you want is to execute those lines in the snippet that is called by AJAX? correct? If that is a case get rid of <script> tags and use  `eval(req.responseText);`

Comment: Thanks for the tip on eval(), that helped a bit. I have now revised my predicament, as stated above.

Comment: @Sooie The reason is tht response text will get returned only after page returns 200 and state of 4 (after is loaded). Try the code i posted as anwser and tell me how that went

Comment: @Sooie almost forgot, try to use flush() to push the buffer, otheriwse there wll beno output . see http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request.

Exactly what you can do is, create a simple HTML file and write your JavaScript function there which will call the server methods after some timeout period or call it in loop or recurse your function, whichever you like. Can I see the working sample of your problem. So that I can assist you better?

Comment: upvoted your first answer here, because it has the right attitude.

Comment: I have updated my code above, reflecting the changes I had commented about before, and hopefully clarified the question being asked :]

Comment: Can you loop it in JavaScript instead of project_locations.php?? I mean, the delay occurs, because there may be very long loop is running there. That's why it takes so much time. And then after all the loop completes, it returns very long string to eval. So what you can do is, start a loop in JavaScript and call xmlHttp requests in that loop with index. And at server side in project_locations.php access that index and return the data for that index only. Am I getting your problem correctly??

Answer (score 1):

As the PHP file is basically generating Javascript code, you could probably just include it as a Javascript file.

With jQuery you could do this with [`$.getScript('project_locations.php')`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/). It should be asynchronous.

Tip: When you're generating JS variables from PHP, use PHP function [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.json-encode.php).

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that response text will be returned when script finishes execution
to get the data as its downloading  you have grab the response text as its download, as such.

```
while(true)
   {
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() //listens to the state chnages
   {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==3) //if its still loading
     {
      eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
     }
   }

    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4) { eval(xmlhttp.responseText);} break; //finished loading get out of for loop
   }
```

Also make sure that php is not buffering any output. as such on top of your file.

```
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression',0);
@ini_set('implicit_flush',1);
@ob_end_clean();

ob_implicit_flush(1);
```